# iPhone: Error uploading audio wav bytes data to server

Tags: ios, audio

I am developing an iOS application. I have to send an audio file to our server programmatically. I am using the following code to send an sample wav audio file to server. Our server accepts only audio file in signed bytes array format for receiving.

```
NSURL *urlPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Crash" ofType:@"wav"]];
NSString *wavbundlepath = [urlPath absoluteString];
NSLog(@"wavbundlepath: %@",wavbundlepath);
NSData *bytes = [wavbundlepath dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"bytes: %@",bytes);

NSString *recordPostLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [bytes length]];

NSMutableString *urlstr = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"http://www.mywebserver/api/UploadFile?Name="];
[urlstr appendString:@"crash"];
[urlstr appendFormat:@"&MemberID=%d", 0];
[urlstr appendFormat:@"&Type=%@",@"Recording"];
[urlstr appendFormat:@"&client=%@",@"ios"];
NSLog(@"urlstr.......%@",urlstr);

NSMutableURLRequest *recordRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
[recordRequest setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlstr]];
[recordRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[recordRequest setValue:recordPostLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[recordRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[recordRequest setHTTPBody:bytes];

NSURLResponse *recordResponse;
NSError *recordError;
NSData *recordResponseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:recordRequest returningResponse:&recordResponse error:&recordError];
NSString *recordResp = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:recordResponseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"recordResp:%@", recordResp);
```

But the problem is, always receving "Input string is not correct." response error.

I am not very much aware of uploading audio bytes to server. Could someone please check this code and tell me this is valid code or not for uploading a wav audio bytes array to server?

Thank you.

---

**UPDATED CODE**

I tried below code as my server side engineer said not to have any other things post body, and it works fine and getting positive response. But, the server is not able to work with format NSData bytes (32 bit elements) what i'm sending, because server side its implemented to receive only array of bytes or signed bytes data format only.

```
NSURL *urlPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Temp" ofType:@"wav"]];

NSString *wavbundlepath = [urlPath absoluteString];
NSLog(@"wavbundlepath: %@",wavbundlepath);

NSData *bytes=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlPath];
NSLog(@"bytes: %@",bytes);

NSString *recordPostLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [bytes length]];

NSMutableString *urlstr = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"http://www.myserver.com/api/UploadFile?Name="];
[urlstr appendString:@"Temp"];
[urlstr appendFormat:@"&MemberID=%d", 0];
[urlstr appendFormat:@"&Type=%@",@"Recording"];
[urlstr appendFormat:@"&client=%@",@"ios"];
NSLog(@"urlstr.......%@",urlstr);

NSMutableURLRequest *recordRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
[recordRequest setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlstr]];

NSInputStream *dataStream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithData:bytes];
[recordRequest setHTTPBodyStream:dataStream];

[recordRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSURLResponse *recordResponse;
NSError *recordError;
NSData *recordResponseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:recordRequest returningResponse:&recordResponse error:&recordError];

NSString *recordResp = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:recordResponseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"recordResp:%@", recordResp);
recordResponceJson = [recordResp JSONValue]; 
NSLog(@"recordResponceJson = %@",recordResponceJson);
recId = [recordResponceJson valueForKey:@"ID"];
NSLog(@"recId....%@", recId);
```

Could someone please guide me, how i can send array of bytes in this http post?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple problems:
First how you're reading the file will not return a valid WAV file:

You should use [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:] to read the bytes.  The way you're reading them it will try to convert the bytes into characters. This will corrupt your wav file.

Second, the content-type of the POST body is probably incorrect. See the line:

```
[recordRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

The audio bytes would not be encoded in x-www-form-urlencoded format. It is more likely that the server would accept a audio/wav or application/octet-stream content type. Check with your server developers to see exactly what the server is expecting.

Also, you may want to check out the NSMutableURLRequest method called  setHTTPBodyStream: that lets you send a file without having to load the entire thing into memory.

Comment: Yes, and NSData is a collection of bytes. So when you add them as the POST body they will be added to the request as a stream of bytes. I strongly recommend you send the body as stream using the setHTTPBodyStream: method rather than loading them into memory.  The stream method will auto-populate the content-length header of the HTTP request so you don't need to make that calculation either.

Comment: Hi, I asked my server side engineer, he said post body should contain only file, no other things. So, i removed other things and also tried using setHttpBodyStream() as you you suggested. Please check the update code in question above. But, it is not doing anything. Empty response has received.

Comment: And also, when i used dataWithContentsOfURL i got exception server error as "[HttpRequestValidationException]: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client". Looks like i'm trying to send huge data(song bytes).

Comment: Our server side engineer is saying, the server expecting array of bytes . or singed bytes.
range of byte is = 0..255.
range of signed byte is = -128...127

Comment: Is it possible to send Byte array (not NSData which is 32 bit elements) via setHTTPBodyStream or setHTTPBody ?  I am able to send the data to server and get the positive response, but server is not able to make the data working as it expects bytes only.

Comment: The setHTTPBodyStream: method will cause the exact bytes of the file to be sent to the server as the POST body.  I did notice that you're no longer setting the content-type, which should be set on this type of post.  Also, have your network engineer set the maximum upload size many servers set this to a pretty small value and it may be smaller than the size of the file.

Comment: Also, you may want to use the Charles proxy (www.charlesproxy.com) to trace the contents of the HTTP request and response between the phone and the server to see exactly what is being communicated between the two of them.  This may enable you and the network engineer to have a common frame of reference for solving the problem.

Comment: I tried the updated code( please see the question above, i added updated code) as my server side engineer said not to have any other things in the post body, and it works fine and getting positive response now. But, the server is not able to work with the format NSData bytes (32 bit elements) what i'm sending for audio wav, because server side its implemented to receive and work with only array of bytes or signed bytes data format only.

Comment: You and your network engineer are over thinking the problem. NSData objects refer to a byte buffer. It's just a pointer to a punch of bytes with a value that indicates how many bytes are in the buffer. The 32 bit reference in NSData is for the data length. When you transmit a NSData buffer it is transmitted as a stream of bytes. I suggest that if the byte stream is getting received and acknowledged by the server then later appears corrupt, then something later is corrupting it, or maybe the original file wasn't a Wav file at all.

Comment: Application is sending wav file only, i think dataWithContentsOfURL is giving such huge data for even a small wav files, which would definitely cannot be uploaded to any server. This is what we are seeing.

Comment: How big is the Wav file on the phone and what is the resulting content-size header when it is transmitted?

Comment: The size of the file is 545 kb is getting huge output from NSData (NSLog(@"NsDataOutput: %@", pData);) and server is unable to proceed and gives failure response as  "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client "

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12118/discussion-between-user213199-and-jack-cox)